# How to log in to the multiple server using ssh and run a checksum command on a file

Tags: ssh, aix

```
#!/bin/bash

SERVER_LIST='./full.lst'

while read REMOTE_SERVER
do
        ssh $REMOTE_SERVER cksum ./SCRIPTS_REPOSITORY/PWD_CHANGE/infra_files/Master_file.sh
done < $SERVER_LIST
```

I am trying to login to different servers from a given list and all the servers have a passwordless setup.

Have tried the above script but i am not able to achieve that.

It would be helpful if anyone can correct me on what am i doing wrong here.

Comment: What kind of error/problem you get?

Comment: Use quotes: `ssh remoteuser@remotehost 'command to exec'`

Comment: for i in `cat full.lst`  do ssh $i "cksum ~/file done ## this worked for me